# How to update an input field after multiplying it by two

Tags: javascript, html

How are you today? I am new to coding but am making my best effort. I am trying to build my own personal bitcoin casino website.

I am trying to take the value of an input field and then multiply that value by 2 by clicking a button that says 'X2'. Then I need the input field to display this new number so that the user can make a bet of that size.

I have tried everything I can think of over the last 3 days and am still unable to do this. Any and all help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>My Bitcoin Casino</title>
</head>

<body>
<button type="button" onclick="MultiplyWagerFunction()">X2</button>

<form>
<input type="text" id="wagerBox" value="0.00000001"></form>

<script>
function MultiplyWagerFunction() {
var wager = document.getElementById("wagerBox").value;
var wagerUpdate = wager*2;
oFormObject.elements["wagerBox"].value = 'wagerUpdate';
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It could be that you're setting the value to the string `'wagerUpdate'` because you're wrapping it around single-quotes, instead of the value of the variable `wagerUpdate`.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("wagerBox").value = 10;
```

This way you can set value of this input to 10.

Personally I recommend you to do this this way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="wage"/>
        <input type="button" id="timesTwo" value="X2"/>
        <script>
            var wageInput = document.getElementById("wage");
            var button = document.getElementById("timesTwo");
            button.addEventListener("click", function(){
                wageInput.value = parseInt(wageInput.value) * 2;
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

There is full explanation about how "addEventListener" works:
 [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp)

There is about parseInt() function: [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)

If you got any questions don't be afraid to ask in comments.

Comment: Thank you, that's a very interesting approach. It is quite different to what I was doing but has merit I'm sure. I have some learning to do to implement this method.

Comment: You don't need to use parseInt. That's redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

The problem was that you were trying to modify the value with "wagerUpdate"
Also, you need to assign the value to the same input control which in below code is elem.

```
function MultiplyWagerFunction() {
            var elem= document.getElementById("wagerBox");
            var wagerUpdate = elem.value * 2;
            elem.value = wagerUpdate;
    }
```

Comment: It works now!  I had something similar before but didn't have the '+' next to wagerUpdate. Thank you so much. I'm feeling much better now. Cheers

Comment: Great if it makes you feel better. Cheers! :) Updated `+` part.

Answer (score 0):

Your var wagerUpdate needs to be called without the quotes. **See below**
       oFormObject.elements["wagerBox"].value = wagerUpdate;

Answer (score 0):

this will work

```
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="MultiplyWagerFunction()">X2</button>

<form>
<input type="text" id="wagerBox" value="0.000001">
</form>

<script>
function MultiplyWagerFunction() {
var wager = document.getElementById("wagerBox");
var wagerValue = wager.value;
var wagerUpdate =  wagerValue * 2;
wager.value = wagerUpdate;
}
</script>
</body>
```

Freddy

Comment: Great. I really like what you have done here and will definitely use this code. Thanks again, very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not exactly what you need, but if you use jquery you could do this

```
MultiplyWagerFunction(){
    var box = $("#wagerBox");
    box.val(box.val()*2);
}
```

Here box is defined to contain the `wagerBox` element and then the function `val()` is used in two different ways, it takes the value in the box, multiply it times 2 and the result is used to set the new value of the box.

Or if you want to be a little more verbose you also could do

```
MultiplyWagerFunction(){
    var box = $("#wagerBox");
    var newValue = box.val()*2;
    box.val(newValue);
}
```

Hope this could be useful.